# How to work with html code readed on Java?

Tags: java, html

I know how to read the HTML code of a website, for example, the next java code reads all the HTML code from  `http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/en/fc-barcelona/startseite/verein_131.html`  this is a website that shows all the football players of F.C. Barcelona.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class ReadWebPage {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String urltext = "http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/en/fc-barcelona/startseite/verein_131.html";
    URL url = new URL(urltext);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url
      .openStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
      // Process each line.
      System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
  }
}
```

OK, but now I need to work with the HTML code, I need to obtain the names ("Valdés, Victor", "Pinto, José Manuel", etc...) and the positions (Goalkeeper, Defence, Midfield, Striker) of each of the players of the team. For example, I need to create an `ArrayList <String> PlayerNames` and an `ArrayList <String> PlayerPositions` and put on these arrays all the names and positions of all the players.

How I can do it??? I can't find the code example that can do it on google..... **code examples are welcome**

thanks

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net), which will give you access to the DOM tree of the HTML page, and even execute JavaScript in case the data are dynamically put in the page using AJAX.

You could also use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/): no JavaScript, but more lightweight and support for CSS selectors.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard at all. Examine the HTML source code carefully: the table containing the players has the ID "spieler". You just have to do a getElementById("spieler") to get this table. With JSoup, document.select("#spieler td.s10 a") should return all the <a> elements containing the player name. Just one line of code.

Comment: please can you edit your answer and give me the code example that does that and put all the names of the players into a arraylist of strings??? i can't achieve it

Comment: Ask another question, showing what you have tried and explaining what you don't understand.

Comment: there are a lot of "spieler" tag's on the code, please don't post without checking if your answer is correct, because this i am asking for code example, because it is not possible to do with the answer you are giving to me

Comment: @AndroidUser99: Go back to school learn politeness, and reading. There is only one element having the **ID** spieler. As in <table id="spieler"> If you don't know anything about HTML, and don't respect the persons who help you for free, you'll never be able to do anything. If you want some free code without trying to understand and learn, then hire a developer. My fee is 600€ per day.

Comment: Great answer - JSoup is great.  Too bad the OP just wants to cut and paste.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best approach is first to purify HTML code into the valid XHTML form, and them apply XSL transformation - for retrieving some part of information you can use XPATH expressions. The best available html tag balancer is in my opinion neko HTML (http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: please can you give me the code example that does this with the name of the players at least? i'm starting on java and html and this is too hard for me, like the answer of JB Nizet

Comment: @Android: through study and effort, you can learn to over come that "too hard" bit. Quit asking for *teh codez*.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to take a look at [htmlparser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)

I used this for something similar.

Usage something like this:

```
Parser fullWebpage = new Parser("WEBADDRESS");
NodeList nl = fullWebpage.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new TagNameFilter("<insert html tag>"));

        NodeList tds  = nodes.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new TagNameFilter("a"),true);

            String data =  tds.toHtml();
```

Comment: thanks but this code didn't work for me, because the website haves a lot of nodes with the same tag that the nodes that haves the name of the players and the position of the players... :(

Answer (score 0):

Java has its own, built-in HTML parser. A positive feature of this parser it that it is error tolerant and would assume some tags even if they are missing or misspelled. While called swing.text.html.Parser, it has actually nothing shared with Swing (and with text only as much as HTML is a text). Use [ParserDelegator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/parser/ParserDelegator.html). You need to write a [callback](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback.html) for use with this parser, otherwise it is not complex to use. The code example (written as a ParserDelegator test) can be found [here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~awl03/cgi-bin/trac.cgi/miro/browser/trunk/gcc/libjava/classpath/testsuite/javax.swing.text.html.parser/test/gnu/javax/swing/text/html/parser/Parser_Test.java?rev=31). Some say it is a reminder of the [HotJava browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotJava). The only problem with it, seems not upgraded to the most recent versions of HTML.

The simple code example would be

```
Reader reader; // read HTML from somewhere
HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback callback = new MyCallBack(); // Implement that interface.
ParserDelegator delegator = new ParserDelegator();
delegator.parse(reader, callback, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a link that is just what you was looking for:
http://tiny-url.org/work_with_html_java