# HTML parsing for getting RSS feed in android

Tags: android, rss, html-parsing

I am trying to develop an app to get the RSS feeds from http://xxx.xxx.com/xxxxxblog .
Can someone help me with the HTML parsing to get the feeds?

Answer (score 0):

You can try JSoup to parse the HTML.

It is very simple to use and well documented, you should not have too much trouble parsing your page.

You can find how to do that from this page

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

It uses different html tag to parse data between that tag.

Comment: Well Thanks Chinmoy, but the above link makes use of Jquerry or CSS. Is there anything that uses Java?

Answer (score 0):

The feeds on this web page seem clearly delimited by `<dc:subject>` tag.
As you only need to get the feeds, the shortest way may be better to get the feed boundaries with regular expression that would also capture the header (something like `<dc:subject>(.*?)</dc:subject>`). Read line by line, once you detect the expression - this is the start of the feed. Maybe it is philosophically not the most right way and we should parse all HTML instead but why to run unnecessary code ...

There is no lack of Java built-in parsers either, starting from Java's built in HTML parser and continuing to various alternative libraries that in some cases may fit better, some also suggest to use XML parser (XPath). Various solutions are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049515/how-to-work-with-html-code-readed-on-java/7049831#7049831).

Answer (score 0):

please try

Use this example code to create RSS reader that is actually can handle namespace extensions

https://github.com/dodyg/AndroidRivers/blob/master/src/com/silverkeytech/android_rivers/xml/RssParser.kt

The library underlying this code is this https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/simple-java-xml-parser.

It works very well in Android as well.